# Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence of partial sums of $\sum a_{n}$. If the series diverges, can $(s_n)$ be a bounded sequence? What about bounded & increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I was thinking that the answer is there can be a bounded sequence, but I am not sure how to go about proving this.

Comment: Clearly yes to your first question, take say $a_n=(-1)^n$. For the second: bounded increasing sequences converge.

Comment: Think about the series $\sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n$ for your first question. And for the second, how can a divergent sequence be bounded *and* increasing, because the latter condition would force convergence by Bolzano-Weierstrass; unless you mean bounded below.

Comment: @JohnB Thank you. 

I am sort of lost on how the theorem you mention helps. Does that mean that a bounded, increasing sequence must have a converging sequence of partial sums?

Comment: You should replace "diverges" with "does not admit a limit"

Comment: @junkquill correct me if I am wrong, but wouldn't something like $(s_n)=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ be both bounded and increasing?

Comment: @MaurizioMoreschi just wondering, what is the difference between these two? I put diverges in the question simply due to the character limit. But would changing the phrasing actually change the meaning?

Comment: Absolutely, but clearly $(s_n)$ is not a sequence of partial sums, is it? So, it doesn't describe a diverging series that your question assumes

Comment: @JohnB means that any bounded, increasing sequence will converge. In your case, the sequence is a sequence of partial sum

Comment: @MohammedShahid Saying that the series diverges means that $(s_n)_n$ tends to $\pm \infty$. Here it is clear that is not what you meant of course.

Comment: Actually, by definition a divergent series is a series which is not convergent. Or a series where the limit of the sequence $(s_n)$ doesn't exist or is properly diverging.

Comment: @junkquill that makes sense in regards to what you said about $(s_n)$. To be honest, I am not sure what the question is asking in particular, which is why I posted the question. I guess I should go ask the professor if he just meant bounded below and increasing?

Or perhaps the answer is simply no, $(s_n)$ can not be bounded and increasing?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on your local definition of *divergent series*. According to the terminology I am used to, any divergent series has unbounded partial sums. But if you call *divergent* any series which is not convergent, $$ \sum_{n\geq 1} (-1)^n $$
is a *divergent* series with bounded partial sums. According to my terminology, such series is neither convergent or divergent.

Comment: The universal canon of divergence is nonconvergence.

Comment: @JohnB: not so *universal*, if they taught me something different, namely that $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n$ is said to be divergent if $\lim_{N\to +\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n$ is either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: Just came across this related post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2986481/big-list-proposed-but-failed-terminology-proposals-by-famous-mathematicians :)